# Pass the apiKey got from a POST to a GET request in node.js

Tags: node.js, post, get

In nodejs, I am able to successfully, make a POST request and get an API key. I need to re-use this API key for further requests via a GET. How do I re-use apiKey result got from the initial POST request in subsequent GET requests?.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!!

```
var request = require('request');

var uri = 'example.com';
var user = 'user';
var pass = 'password';
var token = "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJIUzUxMiJ9";

//POST
request.post(
  {
    headers: {'content-type' : 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},    
    url: uri,   
    rejectUnauthorized: false,      
    form: { email: user, username: user, password: pass, trustToken: token }
  },
  function(err, httpResponse, body) {
    if (err) {
      return console.error('post failed:', err);
    }

    var obj = JSON.parse(body);
    //authToken = json.data.authToken;
    //userId = json.data.userId;
    console.log('Post successful!  Server responded with:', body);
    
    var keys = Object.keys(obj);
    apiKey = obj[keys[0]];
   }  
);


//GET
var Token = {{apiKey}};
console.log(Token);


const options = {
    url: 'https://example.com/ask/search/docs',
    method: 'GET',
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
        'User-Agent': 'my-reddit-client'
    },
    
    form: { 
            apiToken: {{apiKey}}, 
            question: "change probability", 
            stopWords: "false",
            language: "en",
            start: "0",
            rows: "2",
            project:{"projectId":"1752","projectName":"Mars"}
        }
};

request(options, function(err, res, body) {
    let json = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(json);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the key in the request header and send it with every request.

```
const options = {
url: 'https://example.com/ask/search/docs',
method: 'GET',
headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Accept-Charset': 'utf-8',
    'User-Agent': 'my-reddit-client',
    'x-auth-token': Token
},

form: { 
        question: "change probability", 
        stopWords: "false",
        language: "en",
        start: "0",
        rows: "2",
        project:{"projectId":"1752","projectName":"Mars"}
    }
```

};

Then you can have a code on your server basically a middleware to extract it from the request and authenticate the request.

You can save the token in the session storage. If you are planning to keep the token alive for multiple days like Facebook etc, then you can use HTTP secure cookies.

Comment: Thanks for the reploy. Sorry I guess my question was a bit ambiguous. I mean I cannot get the value of apiKey outside the POST function. I got the below error: 

var Token = apiKey;
            ^

ReferenceError: apiKey is not defined